# Set a different Firebase project for single Android app release and debug builds

Tags: android, firebase, debugging, notifications, release-management

I am developing a single android application. I am using Firebase services(notifications, database etc) to back this android app functionality. Generally we have debug and release environments for android app. I don't have any flavours as of now. I want to make android app use separate Firebase project for debug & release environment to keep data separation. How to achieve this ? How to create separate firebase projects and integrate in Android app ? How to manage google `services.json` file for release and debug